# Why is docker compose trying to pull an image instead of creating a new one?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I reinstalled docker on my Ubuntu server and now I am trying to rebuild and run a docker container using `docker-compose` but it seems like there is an error in pulling. How can I work around this, and why does this happen?

docker-compose:

```
version: "3.7"

networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: network

services:
  mysql:
    ports:
      - "13306:3306"
    container_name: mysql
    #environment:
    #  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=dbPass
    image: mysql
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:8

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE db
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=dbPass

COPY ./scripts/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Input command:
`docker-compose up --build`

Error message:

```
Pulling mydb (mysql:)...
ERROR: The image for the service you're trying to recreate has been removed. If you continue, volume data could be lost. Consider backing up your data before continuing.

Continue with the new image? [yN]n
ERROR: pull access denied for mysql:, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Comment: I've ran using your files and it worked, are you there are no volumes? could you run `docker ps -a --no-trunc --format "{{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Mounts}}"` ?

Comment: 2ede29ec3c646108c86d2e9c08a0ec5c12ee6315ab6cfcb9b592bb95c73cdc8b        automate_java   /usr/local/sandbox
509a44ef8c58536bfab0fec857cca23a477b1b76e4429bc1773a4ad7f6f8e505        python_good_app /usr/local/sandbox
38c0827ecb7c14faa9c33d3968fb35705614a770059962c8ead40b6121cd2ef8        python_bad_app  /usr/local/sandbox
d1698a6f12ff15bee44a83f587e111848598a4ba0c3742ad7636c8e34b7bdd39        sweet_chaplygin

Comment: @juanfontes I believe it is due to the fact that I reinstalled docker

Comment: yea, it could be the reason.. I would say, if you don't have anything important, you can just delete everything by `docker system prune --all`. Just be aware that will delete EVERYTHING like containers, volumes, images networks and etc.

Comment: @juanfontes I have done that and still getting the same error message :(

Comment: Fixed, I forgot to add the build property in docker compose. Silly me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten to add the build property in the compose file. Which causes docker to try to fetch the image based on what is defined.

```
version: "3.7"

networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: network

services:
  mysql:
    ports:
      - "13306:3306"
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql
    build: .
```

Comment: Careful!  If you specify both `image:` and `build:`, Docker will overwrite the named `image:` with the results of the Dockerfile build.  That means you now have a local image named `mysql` that is _not_ the Docker Hub image, and this is a potential source of problems if you rebuild.  Unless you're pushing to a registry (which has a specific syntax) it's safe to leave off `image:` here and let Compose pick a name.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for your input. Will make changes on my work :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you removed the image you created with the volume, you forgot to also remove the volume. I think there is 2 solutions for this:

1. Delete your volume using `docker volume rm specific-volume-name` (see [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_rm/))
2. Recreate the build using new volume by adding `-V` option (see [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/))

Comment: Thanks for your answer, there are no available volumes when I try ```docker volume ls```.

Comment: @yungweezy can you please include your docker compose file?

Comment: I have just added the dockerfile and docker-compose file

Answer (score 0):

Set `pull_policy` in your compose file to set the precedence between pull, build, and local cache:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#pull_policy